# How do I specify different libraries for a static Qt project?

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

For my Qt project, I have the normal debug and release build configurations using the standard version of qmake, however I also need to build static (Windows 64-bit) versions of my project using a different, static build of qmake. I am currently doing the static build using the command line and a separete .pro file, however I would prefer to do this with the same .pro file I use for the non-static versions, and from within Qt creator if possible.

I have already created a kit for the static version of qmake, my problem now is that I can't get qmake to link my project against the proper libraries (I have separate library versions for debug, release, and static builds). My pro file looks like this:

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release|static ) {
    #debug build
    LIBS += ../third-party-library/debug/library.lib
}

CONFIG( release, debug|release|static ) {
    CONFIG(static, debug|release|static) {
        #static release build
        LIBS += ../third-party-library/static/library.lib
    } else {
        #non-static release build
        LIBS += ../third-party-library/release/library.lib
    }
}
```

In the project settings for the release build, I'm calling qmake like this:

```
qmake.exe MyProject.pro -spec win32-msvc "CONFIG+=static"
```

My question is how do I add an additional build configuration besides the usual debug/release ones, and how do I specify specific libraries for it?

Comment: In QtCreator go to Projects->Build Settings->Edit build configuration->Add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your qmake definition is a little of. The `CONFIG(debug, debug|release)` syntax is a special construct, as always both are defined, and this finds out witch build is actually used. For static, thats not the case, so simply define it as:

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release ) {
    #debug build
    LIBS += ../third-party-library/debug/library.lib
} else:CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
    static {
        #static release build
        LIBS += ../third-party-library/static/library.lib
    } else {
        #non-static release build
        LIBS += ../third-party-library/release/library.lib
    }
}
```

For why this does not work with `debug` and `release` and thus the special construct is needed, read here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#config-config

Using `static` like that only works because qmake reads such conditions from the `CONFIG` variable. It's basically short for `contains(CONFIG, static)`.

Comment: Hey, this worked. I ended up using the more verbose `contains(CONFIG, static)` syntax. Thank you.